# ServiceStack F# sample fails starting

Tags: f#, mono, servicestack

I'm trying to run [this Self Hosting example](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting), using latest ServiceStack release (4.0.3) and latest Mono/F# (3.2.5).

It fails with an exception on `appHost.Init()`:

> { System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Virtual file not found File name: '<>.FSharpSignatureData.'
>   at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.ResourceVirtualDirectory.CreateVirtualFile (System.String resourceName) [0x00033] in <>/ServiceStack/VirtualPath/ResourceVirtualDirectory.cs:99 }   System.IO.FileNotFoundException

The same does not happen with the C# sample.

Apparently, it looks for some files added as resources in F# assemblies but not mapped to a physical file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# does some 'meta data caching' that puts resources (FSharpSignatureData, FSharpOptimizationData) into the assembly. This causes issues when ServiceStack sets up its virtual file system since it wants to map these resources to actual files (I think).

You can get past this by adding the flag [--nointerfacedata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) to the build/compile steps. (in VS Properties > Build > 'Other flags')

I've been meaning to post this to the GitHub issues page.

Comment: OK, I will try to check if that flags works also in latest Xamarin Studio (I'm using Mono implementation for OSX)